# What cron expression would I use to run a script every first Tuesday of the month

Tags: shell, cron, expression, splunk

My supervisor and I are on a Splunk server trying to put in a shell script and it needs to be done with a cron expression. We searched through different generators and can't seem to find what that expression would be.

Splunk uses the old 5 character expression, not the updated 7 for cron.
Could you help?

Thank you!

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/429617

Comment: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.1/Alert/CronExpressions  Is this the Splunk to which you are referring?

Comment: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.1/Alert/CronExpressions has an example for running on the first Monday at the bottom. That should give you an idea for how to do it on the first Tuesday.